# How do I search for text in Gems and External Libraries in RubyMine?

Tags: rubymine, rubymine-7

I'm trying to search for text in gems in the "External Libraries" section of my RubyMine project, without having to manually find the Gem directory in the file system. Unfortunately, the 'Find in Path' dialog doesn't seem to offer any options for 'Find in External Libraries'. There are also no right-click find options for the Gems.

What is the best way to search for text in External Libraries/Gems in RubyMine?

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer here:

http://makandracards.com/brainchild/34379-rubymine-search-in-external-libraries

The trick is to try and do the search on a subfolder of a gem. Then you can edit the path to that gem to include the entire gem or all of your gems.

Comment: Seems like the link is dead. Perhaps https://makandracards.com/makandra/28473-search-everywhere-in-rubymine instead?